# How to get feature importances with column names after randomizedsearch and one hot encoded data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I wrote following code block. After i found the best estimator, i want to learn feature importance of the model. But i couldn't figure it out how to do it correctly with column names.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories=unique_list, sparse=False)

col_transformers = ColumnTransformer([
                          ("scaler_onestep", scaler, numerical_columns),
                          ("ohe_onestep", ohe, categorical_columns)])


param_grid = {
        'XGB__estimator__max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 10],
        'XGB__estimator__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1],
        'XGB__estimator__n_estimators': [100]}

model = MultiOutputClassifier(xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic"))

#Define a pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([("preprocessing", col_transformers), ("XGB", model)])

rs_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, n_iter=3,
                            n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, cv=2, scoring="accuracy", refit=True, random_state=42)

rs_clf.fit(X, y)
```

This gives me the result of feature importances for first label.

```
rs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps["XGB"].estimators_[0].feature_importances_
```

This gives me the catagories.

```
rs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps["preprocessing"].transformers[1][1].categories
```

result has 389 columns, X has 279 columns,  so i can not write it directly, how can i do that for one hot encoded data?
How can i find this 389 columns names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_feature_names` method is going to be of great help here.  At the moment, `StandardScaler` doesn't support it; since xgboost is completely unaffected by feature scaling, I would suggest dropping it and replacing the numerical portion of the `ColumnTransformer` with `"passthrough"`.  Then `rs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps["preprocessing"].get_feature_names()` should give the features in the order they arrive to XGB.

Comment: I don't think `get_feature_names` will return any features that are not used by the one-hot-encoder. So any columns not in `categorical_columns` will not be returned and need to be added afterward.

Comment: @Shaido, the `ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names` method does include names from passthroughs and remainder (in the latest version at least).

Comment: ... but it would break if any of the transformers don't have their own `get_feature_names`, hence the suggestion to drop the scaler. Otherwise, yes, using the `OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names` and manually gluing on the other names would work.